# Convert a yyyymm format to date in R?

Tags: r, datetime

The year and month is represented as 201603 representing March,2016.
How to convert this numerical value into date format like 
"March-2016" or "2016-03" in R?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A date should always have a given day, therefore consider to add the day at the end of `YYYYMM` (in the example below `01` the first day of the month). Convert the `numeric` value to `character` and the `character` to a `Date`:

`as.Date(paste0(as.character(201603), '01'), format='%Y%m%d')`

Comment: But it will not solve the problem. The output is "2016-12-01" which is incorrect.

Comment: Yes %m solved the problem

Comment: You can use library(zoo) with following line to get the solution. as.yearmon(as.character(201603), "%Y%m") and it display [1] "Mar 2016" as output in R console.